# Why docker container name has an random number at the end after creating docker sevice

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

after I create a docker service using the below code

```
docker service create --name db --network era-networkkk -p 3306:3306 --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/data/mysql,destination=/var/lib/mysql schema
```

and when I check the services using

```
docker services ls
```

it shows the name as db

but when I use the command

```
docker ps
```

container name have some randomly generated numbers after the name

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the printout of these commands?

Comment: The IDs are there by design to support things like rolling updates. Is removing the ID the problem you are trying to solve, or are there commands using the container name you are trying to make work with a swarm service?

Answer (score 0):

I think that behaviour is absolutely intended. What if your swarm is configured to start multiple containers of the same image on a single swarm node? These containers can't have the same name. So there has to be a suffix on the container names so there is no name collision. Why would you want to influence the container's names? Normally when working with clusters you are working on service level instead of container level.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is that when you create a service you don't necessarily care what the container names are.  You would usually create a service when docker is in swarm mode.  With swarm mode you set up a cluster of nodes, I guess you only have one node for dev purposes.  However when you have more than one cluster then the service would create as many containers as you specify with the --replicas option.  Any requests to your application would then be load balanced across the containers in your cluster via the service.

Have a look at the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/ it may help to clarify how all of this works.